# Symfony routes fail over https, fine in http

Tags: symfony, https, routes

So I am not sure if this is a configuration issue or server issue. I have to think it's a configuration issue because the vhost is setup correctly to allow for ssl connections and the certificate doesn't have any issues.

Whenever I try to access a route on https, it return not found, index.php was not found on this server. But if I remove the 's' and access via http, it works fine and always has. Has anyone had this happen before? Any advice is appreciated. I don't know where the config for this(if there is one) is at to post my code.

Comment: Symfony should not care if you access it over http or https. Can you show the vHost config, are you sure `DocumentRoot` is set up properly? And do you have the config in vHost or .htaccess (if the latter: do you allow Override?)

Comment: I'm using vhosts, but I don't have access to the vhost unfortunately. I can show you what is in the ssl_error log. Seems like something with the vhost for sure after looking at that.    AH01276: Cannot serve directory /path/to/site/web: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: Try to route to /path/to/site instead (without /web) and let the .htaccess inside take care?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Had nothing to do with Symfony, as @Kero suggested. Turns out my vhost was incorrectly configured on port 443.